# Era in NodaTime

Tags: c#, nodatime

I noticed that of the date-related types -- **LocalDate**, **LocalDateTime**, **OffsetDateTime**, **ZonedDateTime** -- only **LocalDate** accepts era as a construction parameter:

```
public LocalDate(int year, int month, int day);
public LocalDate(Era era, int yearOfEra, int month, int day, [NotNullAttribute] CalendarSystem calendar);
```

Are the era-based constructors only provided as a matter of convenience? And if so, why is it not extended to other types which limit constructors to non-era values? For instance:

```
public LocalDateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute);
```

All of the types have an immutable **Era** parameter. As far as I can tell, the only way to affect **Era** in the other types is by the calendar used during construction.

Would someone be able to explain this design choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mixture of oversight and avoiding massive overloading, basically. It would certainly make logical *sense* to have such a constructor in `LocalDateTime`.

`ZonedDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime` don't have constructors accepting individual components to start with - you're expected to create them from one of the other types. So it's only really `LocalDateTime` that needs anything added.

However, there's then the question of which overloads to add. There are already 8 constructors in `LocalDateTime` - four variants of precision (down to minute, second, millisecond, and tick within millisecond) and two overloads for each of those to accept a `CalendarSystem` or assume ISO. I don't want to double this number of constructors to 16 (and it's already odd that in 2.0 you can't directly construct a value to nanosecond precision with a constructor...)

Use of eras is pretty unusual, so rather than everyone having to pay the complexity cost of having lots of constructors to deal with, it's simpler to just construct a `LocalDate` and a `LocalTime` separately:

```
var ldt = new LocalDate(Era.Xyz, yearOfEra, month, day, calendar) +
          new LocalTime(....);
```

That's simple and still efficient, without the headache of overload blowup.

Comment: The answer provides clarity and makes sense. And just to make sure I am fully tuned in:

Would it be safe to assume then that era could have been excluded from construction altogether without loss of functionality that could be recaptured via additional methods?

For instance, `LocalDate.YearOfEra` property would be replaced by `LocalDate.YearOfEra(Era)`.

Comment: @Tomcat: No, it's important to be able to easily construct dates in a given era, although it's a relatively niche use case. A `LocalDate.YearOfEra(Era)` method wouldn't be able to construct a `LocalDate`, and it wouldn't make much sense as you'd need to know the era first... it's not like you can present a date in 123BC and ask what its year in the AD era is...